# Propagation_requires_new rollbacks suspended transaction

Tags: spring, transactions, propagation

I have following code

@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    EmployeeService employeeService; //to test different behavior

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void requiredPropagationMethod(){

    System.out.println("EmployeeService.requiredPropagationMethod");
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setEmpName("required propagation method employee");
    entityManager.persist(e);
    employeeService.requiresNewPropagationMethod(); //creates a new transaction and suspends old one
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void requiresNewPropagationMethod(){
    System.out.println("EmployeeService.requiresNewPropagationMethod");
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setEmpName("requires new propagation method employee");
    entityManager.persist(e);
    throw new RuntimeException("Roll back requires new method");
}
```

}

after the execution of this code I was expecting the employee with name "required propagation method employee" in Employee table but its not there it means both the transaction were rolled back. But expected behavior is it shuldn't. I need to know why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

Actually when a call from a method to another method is made, the second is not intercepted by the proxy. Here in this example, you are by passing Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW because you are calling it from another method. The second cannot start a new transaction. It is using the same transaction which the first method is using. Therefore, when an exception occured, the first transaction is rolling back.